# How do the symfony required option work?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel, required

I don't know why, but I remembered that when you have a symfony form with required fields not rendered, the `isValid` function do not check for them.

I mean it only check if the widget got a value when you use it. And it seem in my current project that it is wrong.

Is there a setting or something allowing to do this ?

Edit : Here is the form :

```
    class DemandeForm extends BaseDemandeForm
    {
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['DEMANDE_DESC']         = new sfWidgetFormTextarea();
    $this->validatorSchema['DEMANDE_DESC']      = new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true),
    array("required" => str_replace('$1','Description de la demande',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7))));

    $this->validatorSchema['DEMANDE_LIB']      = new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true),
    array("required" => str_replace('$1','Libelle de la demande',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7))));

    $this->widgetSchema['TIERS_ID']         = new crfcWidgetAutocomplete();
    $this->validatorSchema['TIERS_ID']      = new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true),
    array("required" => str_replace('$1','Tiers',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7))));

    $bat_choices = $this->getOption('bat_choices');
    $this->widgetSchema['BAT_CODE']         = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $bat_choices , 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['BAT_CODE']      = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($bat_choices),'required' => false)
    );

    $local_choices = $this->getOption('local_choices');
    $this->widgetSchema['LOCAL_CODE']       = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $local_choices, 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['LOCAL_CODE']    = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($local_choices),'required' => false)
    );

    $site_choices = $this->getOption('site_choices');
    $this->widgetSchema['SITE_CODE']       = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $site_choices, 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['SITE_CODE']    = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($site_choices),'required' => false)
    );

    $ress = Array(""=>"") + EnumereValeurPeer::getByType('FONCTIONS',true);
    $this->widgetSchema['FONCTION_EVAL_NUMINT']         = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $ress , 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['FONCTION_EVAL_NUMINT']      = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($ress),'required' => false),
    array("required" => str_replace('$1','Fonction demandeur',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7))));

    $ress = Array(""=>"") + EnumereValeurPeer::getByType('CIRCONSTANCE',true);
    $this->widgetSchema['CIRCONSTANCE_EVAL_NUMINT']       = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $ress, 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['CIRCONSTANCE_EVAL_NUMINT']    = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($ress),'required' => false),
    array("required" => str_replace('$1','Circonstance de la demande',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7))));

    $ress = Array(""=>"") + EnumereValeurPeer::getByType('TRAVAUX',true);
    $this->widgetSchema['CATEGORIE_EVAL_NUMINT']         = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $ress , 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['CATEGORIE_EVAL_NUMINT']      = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($ress),'required' => false),
        array("required" => str_replace('$1','Catégorie de travaux',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7)))
    );

    $ress = Array(""=>"") + EnumereValeurPeer::getByType('QUALIFICATION',true);
    $this->widgetSchema['QUALIFICATION_EVAL_NUMINT']         = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $ress , 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['QUALIFICATION_EVAL_NUMINT']      = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($ress),'required' => true),
        array("required" => str_replace('$1','Qualification',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7)))
    );

    $ress = Array(""=>"") + EnumereValeurPeer::getByType('PROGRAMME',true);
    $this->widgetSchema['PROGRAMME_EVAL_NUMINT']         = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $ress , 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['PROGRAMME_EVAL_NUMINT']      = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($ress),'required' => true),
            array("required" => str_replace('$1','Programme',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7)))
            );

    $ress = Array(""=>"") + EnumereValeurPeer::getByType('SUPPORT',true);
    $this->widgetSchema['SUPPORT_EVAL_NUMINT']         = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $ress , 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false));
    $this->validatorSchema['SUPPORT_EVAL_NUMINT']      = new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($ress),'required' => false),
    array("required" => str_replace('$1','Support',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7))));

    $this->widgetSchema['COMMENTAIRE']         = new sfWidgetFormTextarea();
    $this->validatorSchema['COMMENTAIRE']      = new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false));


    $this->widgetSchema['DEMANDE_DTDEM']                    = new myWidgetFormRichDate();
    $this->validatorSchema['DEMANDE_DTDEM']                 = new sfValidatorDate(array('required' => true, 'date_format'=>'@(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<year>\d{4})@'),
        array('required'=> str_replace('$1','Date de la demande',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7)),
        'bad_format' => str_replace('$1','Date de la demande',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(19)),
        'invalid' => str_replace('$1','Date de la demande',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(19))));

    $this->widgetSchema['DEMANDE_DTFIN']                    = new myWidgetFormRichDate();
    $this->validatorSchema['DEMANDE_DTFIN']                 = new sfValidatorDate(array('required' => true, 'date_format'=>'@(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<year>\d{4})@'),
        array('required'=> str_replace('$1','Date de fin des travax souhaitée',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(7)),
        'bad_format' => str_replace('$1','Date de fin des travax souhaitée',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(19)),
        'invalid' => str_replace('$1','Date de fin des travax souhaitée',MessagePeer::getFrameworkMessageFromNum(19))));

    $this->widgetSchema['DEMANDE_ACCESSIBILITE']            = new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox();
    $this->validatorSchema['DEMANDE_ACCESSIBILITE']         = new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => false));

    $this->widgetSchema['DEMANDE_URGENT']                   = new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox();
    $this->validatorSchema['DEMANDE_URGENT']                = new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => false));

    $this->widgetSchema['DEMANDE_INCENDIE']                 = new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox();
    $this->validatorSchema['DEMANDE_INCENDIE']              = new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => false));

    $this->validatorSchema->setOption('allow_extra_fields' , true);
    $this->validatorSchema->setOption('filter_extra_fields' , false);
  }


}
```

Edit 2 :

The question is : is it normal than the DEMANDE_DTDEM field required, raise a required form field error, whereas he hadn't been rendered ?

Shouldn't a form field be validated only when he was used ?

Comment: And you got an error like "Extra field name."? Ot sth else?

Comment: No, my workflow has 2 steps.  Almost all fields are used in one place in order to create or edit this model.  But 2 are used later in order to validate the model (not the same user). In the validation case, the $this->form->isValid(), raise required errors.  On all the required fields i hadn't used. Is his normal ?

Comment: You are using the same form class for both step?

Comment: Yeah. I don't know why, i thought i was possible. Maybe through workarounds. I'm trying to stay consistent with most of the symfony project i have to work on. And each one was using a same form to different place, and not always with the same fields. I don't think that's a best practice still, but it remove duplicate widget declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the normal behaviour. Fields VALIDATION has nothing to do with rendering.
If you don't want to render a widget you must explicitly remove both widget and validator (with unset or useFields).

If you define a widget and a validator (like in your case), but you don't call to `$form['DTDEM']->render()`, the value will be always empty.

**IT'S VERY IMPORTANT THAT YOU UNDERSTAND THAT**. In this case, the field is required, and then become that error, but if it wasn't required, the `$form->save()` method will always clean the value of the object in your database!

NEVER leave the widgets unrendered. You should do some echo `$form` while debugging to see what widgets are configured, and if you don't want some of them, just remove them in the form `configure()` method (as I said, with unset or useField)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I guess that was another hacky part on a project i had to migrate, which was really hacky on some parts.  So i will make use of different forms, since i have technical liberies on this new projet from scratch).     I guess i didn't run into this problem before, because to some complex business rules, the original guys didn't used the $form->save(), in these cases.

Comment: After some tests i conclude that you are right on the required part. But you are totally wrong on the form->save() part.  A field which is not present does not affect our object value. At least not in symfony 1.4.

Comment: Seem something went wrong on my first tests. Your are right. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: +1 for the important part. Saved my day and isn't documented.

Answer (score 0):

I wish to add a complement to the glerendegui's answer.

What he is said is true in the general case. But, there is an element game changing. The form's option filter_extra_fields(false) alter significantly the rules. And is the reason for my original misunderstanding.

Because with this option set to false, the $form->save() will not set empty values in your objets, when you widget have not been rendered.

This is an important addition, because in all legacy code i have inherited, the use of this option was common, and unchallenged.

Comment: I didn't know about this option. It's good to know. But, anyway, I don't recommend to use it, simply because I don't trust how will filter widgets like multiple-list or checkboxes, and detect if the widget was not rendered or was rendered but user set an empty value

Comment: So far i know one downside to it, the checkboxes widgets don't work properly. Because they send no value when unchecked, so you have to handle it by hand. I don't use this when i can. But i don't have choice when this is legac code :p. But i'm sure you know it.